# Cocoa Touch - Custom UIButton shape

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

How can I make the touchable button area to be of the same shape of the image provided?
Say I have a custom button with a triangle image, how can I make sure that only touches within that triangle will be processed.

Or do I have to do some kind of math in the on touch action function?

Comment: I you do decide to intercept taps, Apple has done all the math for you. See the `containsPoint:` method of `UIBezierPath` (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/containsPoint:)

Answer (score 3):

[OBShapedButton](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton) is a great Project for that

It works by subclassing UIButton and overriding `-pointInside:withEvent:`

```
@implementation OBShapedButton

// UIView uses this method in hitTest:withEvent: to determine which subview 
// should receive a touch event.
// If pointInside:withEvent: returns YES, then the subview’s hierarchy is 
// traversed; otherwise, its branch
// of the view hierarchy is ignored.
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    // Return NO if even super returns NO (i.e. if point lies outside our bounds)
    BOOL superResult = [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
    if (!superResult) {
        return superResult;
    }

    // We can't test the image's alpha channel if the button has no image. 
    // Fall back to super.
    UIImage *buttonImage = [self imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if (buttonImage == nil) {
        return YES;
    }

    CGColorRef pixelColor = [[buttonImage colorAtPixel:point] CGColor];
    CGFloat alpha = CGColorGetAlpha(pixelColor);
    return alpha >= kAlphaVisibleThreshold;
}

@end
```

`[aUIImage colorAtPixel:point]` is a category-method that is attached.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is definitely not provided by the core cocoa touch classes related to a UIButton. I would guess you would have to look into subclassing UIButton and intercepting the taps as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Ole's [OBShapedButton](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton) project should be referenced more on SO.  Thanks to vikingosegundo, who's [my-programming-examples](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples) github has helped in the past, you can see some of what Ole put together to take away the actions from the transparent background part of a custom UIButton.  I added this to my project and was able to get it up and running with these steps.

1. download the project
2. add the UIImage+ColorAtPixel.h/m and OBShapedButton.h/m files to your project folder
3. make sure the .m files are added to your target's Build Phases > Compile Sources list
4. change the UIButton class type of all your buttons to the OBShapedButton class in IB
5. make sure your .png file has a transparent background and make it the "Image" of the button

This project will help anyone who has multiple overlapping UIButtons that have a transparent backgrounds, even if they are in different UIViews or completely covered by another UIButton (e.g you can't select it in IB without Editor > Arrange > Send to Back/Front).  However, if you have a OBShapedButton in a UIView, where part of the transparent UIView is overlapping an OBShapedButton, you can not receive the click or drag event on the UIView covered part of the OBShapedButton, so layer your UIViews with this in mind.

Download Ole and viking's projects for your tutorial collection......DO IT!