# (swift)Custom Shaped Button

Tags: ios, swift

I have some buttons in my app that are in different shapes i.e. not rectangles. For example, [image: two grenade shaped ones]

I want to make it so they can't be clicked in the entire rectangle surrounding them but only in the red area. The background of the images is removed but xcode automatically gives them a rectangle shape. How do I fix this?

Comment: How the shapes are drawn? Are those images or shape layers? In case of layers you could just `hitTest` to detrmine if the tapped point is within the layer

Comment: they are images, how would I go about making shape layers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161992/cocoa-touch-custom-uibutton-shape has some overview of it as you might already have noticed.