# Scaling a button to fit the background image

Tags: ios, swift

Im having an issue here. I want the button to fit the background image's dimensions perfectly.

For example:

[image: Image Example]

As you can see, the box around the "Request Plan" diamond overlaps or goes over the "View Plan" diamond, and in run-time when I click on the "View Plan" diamond it actually clicks on the "Request Plan" diamond because of it overlapping. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: You can create a normal button then rotate it. In this case your background image need to be "rotated" version

Comment: @jokeman I couldnt find an option to rotate, how do I do it

Comment: Try `self.myButton.transform = self.myButton.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI_4))` when init your button

Comment: @jokeman The problem is the "Blue square lines" will still be there even if image is rotated, I need the blue lines in the picture to fit the actual Diamond.

Comment: The code above doesn't rotate the image, it rotates the UIButton

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161992/cocoa-touch-custom-uibutton-shape for the general idea of how to solve this.

Comment: If the "Blue square lines" is the rect of your button, then with my code, your "Blue square lines" will be rotated also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `CustomButton` class extend UIButton then override `pointInside`

```
override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    *we need check at this point inside or outside*
    return self.alphaAtPoint(point) >= 127
}
```

And We can check it by check `alpha` value

```
func alphaAtPoint(point: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
   var pixel: [UInt8] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
   let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
   let alphaInfo = CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)
   let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(&pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, alphaInfo)

   CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y);

   self.layer.renderInContext(context)

   return CGFloat(pixel[3])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard, whatever you want to be equal lengthed just drag to the other object and select "Equal Widths" and "Equal Lengths". Regarding the overlapping, maybe either change the order of the button or view, or recreate it.